# Divide up a rectangle based on pairs of points

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

[Example http://xthlegion.co.uk/images/dividerectangle.png](http://xthlegion.co.uk/images/dividerectangle.png)
[Example http://xthlegion.co.uk/images/dividerectangle2.png](http://xthlegion.co.uk/images/dividerectangle2.png)

If you consider the images above, you can see they are comprised of a single large rectangle broken down into smaller rectangles by pairs of user defined coordinates (each pair in the example images are identified with a different color).

What I'm trying to do is obtain the co-ordinates of those rectangles by only defining the joins. Edges are treated as explicit joins. Order doesn't matter.

Does anyone know the name of the algorithm that does this (I'm sure there's one with a fancy name!) or have some example C# code? I've been struggling trying to do this myself for a while now but am having little success. Yet another total math fail!

**Update:**
Just thought I'd quickly update this question based on the comments I've received.

1. Lines must be straight, so each pair of co-ordinates will align on one axis
2. Co-ordinates must start from either an edge, or the intersection of another pair. The second co-ordinate must end in a similar fashion. Any "orphan" co-ordinates which don't start/end one another join are illegal and I should ignore them for now, snapping should be possible once I finally get my head in gear.
3. Although in this example all the pairs more or less neatly divide the rectangle, this will not be the case in practice and there could be many lines creating rectangles of many sizes.

**2nd Update - it works :)**
[Example http://xthlegion.co.uk/images/dividerectangle3.png](http://xthlegion.co.uk/images/dividerectangle3.png)

Comment: Not that I know the solution either way, but you should mention if the points can be assumed to lie on integral grid points or not. For example, in the left example, does the lower yellow point necessarily have the exact same Y coordinate as it's row neighbors? If not, the resulting polygon will not be a rectangle.
Also consider what happens if the left blue point in the left picture was one point to the right, joining what are now rectangles 1 and 2. The resulting polygon is also not a rectangle.

Comment: Rotem, thanks for the comment. I should have mentioned that, but yes, the coordinates will line up on one axis so that the rectangle can be divided up via straight lines.

Comment: The second edge case I mentioned will be harder to solve, unless you assume it is illegal for the user to create lines which do not maintain complete rectangles.

Comment: Could you please describe the subdivision process in more detail? How does the result look if there are only the two green points from example one? Or just the blue ones? I guess there are some constraints on the point placement you did not mention.

Comment: Rotem, Daniel: I think I should assume that if the lines don't join, it's "illegal" and therefore would be ignored. I'm not about to try and complicate things (yet) by snapping lines together :) So therefore the subdivision would only work for pairs which start from an edge and edge at another edge or another line. If that makes sense.

Comment: Are the rectangles created by repeatedly splitting one existing rectangle into two parts? Black, yellow, blue and finally green in the first example? But this does not work for the second example.

Comment: I think I understand. This constraints seem quiet hard to express...

Comment: No, they are just examples I came up with for testing my code on the theory that equally spaced rectangles would be nice and easy to test. But in practice they could be anywhere, within the constraints I've so far badly described :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to compute is known an [**arrangement of line segments**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrangement_of_lines). (It's not a particularly good name, but it seems to be the name we're stuck with!) To compute it:

1. Find the set of intersections (all points where two line segments meet or cross). This can be computed by the [Bentley–Ottmann algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm). If there are *n* line segments and *k* crossings, this takes O((*n* + *k*) log *n*). (But if you only have a few line segments, it's probably better to use the simple O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) algorithm.)
2. With a bit of extra book-keeping you can record which edges were incident at each intersection, and so compute the [**planar straight-line graph**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_straight-line_graph) (PSLG) corresponding your set of line segments.
3. Convert the PSLG to a [**quad-edge data structure**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quad-edge_data_structure). This takes two steps. First, find edge—edge connections in the data structure by ordering the edges incident to each vertex by angle.
4. Choose an edge that isn't yet connected to two faces, create a face on the unconnected side, and walk around the boundary of that face connecting it to each edge in turn. Repeat until every edge is connected to two faces.

In general, this results in faces other than rectangles (even if all the line segments are axis-aligned and all intersections have integer coordinates), but maybe in your application this doesn't happen, or you can discard the non-rectangular faces.

[image]

Comment: Gareth, thanks for the informative reply. No wonder I was having difficulty trying to come up with a solution on my own, this looks horribly complicated! Seems I have a lot of reading to do before trying to do this again.

Comment: Using this information, I managed to get my original code working (I added a graphic example of the output to the original question rather than polluting comments or answers) and I'm rather pleased. However, I'm not using the Bentley–Ottmann algorithm (unless by accident!) but something that is probably incredibly inefficient by comparison. But it works, thanks very much for the pointers!

Comment: You're welcome. If your picture shows a typical problem instance (with 13 line segments and 23 intersections), then I wouldn't worry about not using Bentley–Ottmann to find the intersections. The O(n^2) algorithm is fine for small instances like this.

Answer (score 2):

The answer assumes the following rule, which I believe is a necessity in any case:

**The user may only subdivide an existing rectangle using a horizontal or vertical line.**

This means that in your first example the order of subdivision would have to be:
**Brown, yellow, blue green.**

For whatever rectangle class you're using, define two extension methods: `SubdivideHorizontal` and `SubdivideVertical`, which will accept the coordinate of subdivision, and will return the two resulting rectangles of the subdivision.
For each rectangle you subdivide, replace it with the two resulting subdividing rectangles and repeat recursively for all subdivisions.

Comment: Would this work for the second example, though? Seems like this approach would only work in the first example and not in the second. At least not how it's represented in the picture.

Answer (score -1):

I would do the following.

1. Create a point on each of the outer 4 corners.
2. Create a point on each user defined point.
3. Create a point whenever a line crosses over an empty point.
4. Run through each square and check if there is a point on all four corners.